# How Should Lexers Be Stateful?

Tags: parsing, languages, grammar, lexer

Aside from modes, Antlr grammars can use "actions" which have to be written in the target language, sometimes seen used to conditionally push and pop from the mode stack.

If I were to make a parser generator, how should the lexer be stateful? Specifically, if I want to accommodate all mutations *that rightfully belong in the lexer* - in the grammar notation, what is the extent of statefulness a lexer definition should be able to express?

Especially when accounting for mode switching, for when the rules of lexemes take on a different shape, or possible layout sensitivities.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the kind of languages and it depends on whether you see statefulness on the input or the output side of the lexer.

- On the input side, lexers are often stateful: If you parse a string between quotes,  the open quote will set a state that makes all subsequent characters be part of the string until the closing quote.  Likewise, the parsing of a floating point number requires some statefulness,  as 0.98 is a float token, whereas 0.98.99 is not.
- On the output side,  lexers are often stateless, in the sense that one token is independent of the previous tokens.

Moreover, in context sensitive languages,  you may have to distinguish for the same input different lexemes,  depending on the parsing context.  One of the approach to this problem is to use a context dependent, stateful lexing.

Answer (score 1):

They should not be stateful.

No mutations rightfully belong in a lexer.

All you're doing is transforming one stream (usually characters) into another (usually strings). That sort of thing is best handled by pure functions.

Capturing comments might be a side effect, but that probably be shouldn't handled in a stateful manner. Managing where you are at in the grammar could be done via a state machine, but more often is simply handled by the call stack.

Comment: I see this answer elsewhere, but I don't see the issue addressed. Maybe "stateful" is not accurate wording, but we establish that you can effectively have two grammars in the same subject file which you might want to parse jointly, like doc annotations and source code. There are cases where rules may change conditionally, which is again where I'm having the issue.

One naive example here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spec/blob/45db7640b161b42e1da754b0755826b3ae9f8e59/grammar/src/main/antlr/KotlinLexer.g4#L48

Comment: @exxjob - sure. That's at the parsing step though, not the lexing step. There's a reason that (almost) every doc block is simply comments for the base language. Lexers should be dead simple. Separate things by whitespace and symbols.

Comment: "That's at the parsing step though" is the linked example a parsing step? These are rules to switch between sublexers. Rules are incompatible and tokens are not the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. Instead of building out the sub-rules for "here are things allowed in a string" it uses this mode trickery for existing rules. I'd have done that differently, but you'll see that sort of optimization in implementations.